# request.getAttribute in servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have the hyperlink `products?categoryId=1`

in the servlet doGet() method

I cant seem to get the value of the categoryId in the browser.
Do i have to use a form submission? I want to use a hyperlink
cant i do it like in asp.net

```
Response.redirect(products?categoryId=1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use request.getParameter(String) instead.

Comment: may I know in what context should request.getAttribute be used?

Comment: for example, request.setAttribute("key", "value") is used for request.getAttribute();